xauth not running in chroot
I created a chroot environment on my computer and enabled a few different programs to run on it. I access this chroot environment through an ssh connection.
One of the application in this chroot is cellxgene that has a graphical display. It launches without any problem but I am not able to forward the graphical display to the client's screen.
I have modified the ssh_config (on the client side) and the sshd_config (on the host side) files to enable X11 forwarding, port forwarding, etc.
sshd_config file:
Match User anonymous
      X11Forwarding yes
      AllowAgentForwarding yes
      AllowTcpForwarding yes
      GatewayPorts yes      
      XAuthLocation /usr/bin/xauth
      ChrootDirectory /anonymous-root

ssh_config file:
Host *
     ForwardAgent yes
     ForwardX11 yes
     XAuthLocation /usr/bin/xauth

However, I keep having the same error message upon connecting with the command ssh -vX anonymous@<ip-address>:
Could not run /usr/bin/xauth -q -

I verified the dependencies for xauth and the permissions on /usr/bin/xauth are:
-rwxr-xr-x 1 anonymous anonymous 56280 Mar 29 13:05 /usr/bin/xauth
I tried a LOT of different things to solve this issue, but so far nothing is doing the trick or even changing the error message to something else.
Any advice on how to go about this would be welcome.
Thanks in advance!

Can you run xauth manually? What is the result?

Yes, I can access a xauth prompt with following message first:
Using authority file /home/user-magictool/.Xauthority
I manually copied the .Xauthority from the computer hosting the chroot.
